# How do you make image rendering with Cairo on Gtk3 faster?

Tags: c, gtk3, cairo

I am migrating an acquisition software from Allegro4 to Gtk3/Cairo and I need to display images on the fly (no GPU acceleration) and Cairo is slow. Under Ubuntu, with Allegro4, displaying a 4Mb image lasted 5 ms, with Cairo it lasts ~40 ms (times compared on the same computer, software compiled with -O3 flags). Curiously, rendering the image on a GtkImage with gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf is 5 times faster than by using Cairo's. Can I optimize Cairo to do it faster ? Or can I draw with Cairo on a GtkImage instead of a DrawingArea in order to use gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf ? (Indeed I need to draw lines over the image). Or can I use gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf on a DrawingArea ?

The codes that I compare are :

(`pix` is an array in memory that contains the image, `imgtk` is a preallocated GtkImage ):

**GtkImage with source pixbuf:**

```
t0 = my_ulclock();
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data (pix, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,   TRUE,   8, w,  h,  stride,  NULL,NULL);
g_object_ref (pixbuf);
gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf (GTK_IMAGE (imgtk), pixbuf);
g_object_unref (pixbuf);
t1 = my_ulclock();
fprintf(stderr,"gtk set image took %g \n",1e3*((double)(t1 - t0))/get_my_ulclocks_per_sec()); fflush(stderr);
```

**Cairo with source surface**

```
cairo_new_path (cr);
cairo_set_antialias (cr,CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE);
cairo_set_tolerance (cr,1);
cairo_set_operator (cr,CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
cairo_rectangle (cr, 0,0,w,h);
cairo_clip(cr);
t0 = my_ulclock();
cairo_surface_t *bitmap = cairo_image_surface_create_for_data(pix, format, w, h, stride);
cairo_set_source_surface(cr, bitmap, 0,0);
t1 = my_ulclock();
fprintf(stderr,"Cairo set_source_surface took %g ms \n",1e3*((double)(t1 - t0))/get_my_ulclocks_per_sec()); fflush(stderr);
t0 = my_ulclock();
cairo_paint(cr);
t1 = my_ulclock();
fprintf(stderr,"Cairo paint took %g ms \n",1e3*((double)(t1 - t0))/get_my_ulclocks_per_sec()); fflush(stderr);
```

That is what I get for an image of 0.03 Mpx:

*gtk set image took 0.028 ms

Cairo set_source_surface took 0.005 ms

Cairo paint took 0.143 ms*

I also tried to use `gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf` with cairo. Now, the function cairo_paint is fast but gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf is extremely slow compared to `cairo_set_source_surface` which is almost instantaneous.

**Cairo with source pixbuf**

```
cairo_new_path (cr);
cairo_set_antialias (cr,CAIRO_ANTIALIAS_NONE);
cairo_set_tolerance (cr,1);
cairo_set_operator (cr,CAIRO_OPERATOR_SOURCE);
cairo_rectangle (cr, 0,0,w,h);
cairo_clip(cr);
GdkPixbuf *pixbuf = gdk_pixbuf_new_from_data (pix, GDK_COLORSPACE_RGB,   TRUE,   8, w,  h,  stride,  NULL,NULL);
t0 = my_ulclock();
gdk_cairo_set_source_pixbuf(cr, pixbuf, 0,0);
t1 = my_ulclock();
fprintf(stderr,"Gdk cairo set source pixbuf took %g ms \n",1e3*((double)(t1 - t0))/get_my_ulclocks_per_sec()); fflush(stderr);
t0 = my_ulclock();
cairo_paint(cr);
t1 = my_ulclock();
fprintf(stderr,"Cairo paint took %g ms \n",1e3*((double)(t1 - t0))/get_my_ulclocks_per_sec()); fflush(stderr);
```

and I got

*Gdk cairo set source pixbuf took 2.411 ms

Cairo paint took 0.012 ms*

Comment: "Curiously, rendering the image on a GtkImage with gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf is 5 times faster than by using Cairo's" - How are you measuring the rendering time? `gtk_image_set_from_pixbuf` does not render the pixbuf, but just keeps a reference to it. The actual rendering happens outside of this call.